# Efficiently sum elements of a numpy array corresponding to indices matched by another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to find sum of the rows corresponding to indexes matching another numpy.

It is better demonstrated with the following example.

```
A=np.array(['a-1','b-1','b-1','c-2','a-1','b-1','c-2']);
b = np.array([1.21,2.34,1.2,2.8,10.0,0.9,8.4]);;
```

I prefer the output to be a dictionary, such that

```
d['a-1'] = 1.21 + 10.0 = 11.21
d['b-1'] = 2.34 + 1.2 + 0.9 = 4.44
d['c-2'] = 2.8 + 8.4 = 11.2
```

the result is the sum of the elements of the b array corresponding to the indexes where same value appears in the A array.  Is there an efficient way to do this ?. My arrays are large (orders of millions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use a combination of [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
In [48]: unq, ids = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)

In [49]: dict(zip(unq, np.bincount(ids, b)))
Out[49]: 
{'a-1': 11.210000000000001,
 'b-1': 4.4400000000000004,
 'c-2': 11.199999999999999}
```

So, `np.unique` gives us unique integer mapping for each of the strings in `A`, which are then fed to `np.bincount` that uses those integers as bins for bin based weighted summations, with weights from `b`.

**Approach #2 (Specific case)**

Assuming that the strings in `A` are always of `3` characters, a faster way would be with converting those strings to numerals and then use those as the input to `np.unique`. The idea is that `np.unique` would work faster with numerals than strings.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
In [141]: n = A.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,3).dot(256**np.arange(3))

In [142]: unq, st, ids = np.unique(n, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)

In [143]: dict(zip(A[st], np.bincount(ids, b)))
Out[143]: 
{'a-1': 11.210000000000001,
 'b-1': 4.4400000000000004,
 'c-2': 11.199999999999999}
```

The magical part is that the `viewing` after reshaping stays as a view and as such should be pretty efficient :

```
In [150]: np.shares_memory(A,A.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,3))
Out[150]: True
```

Or we could use the `axis` parameter of `np.unique` (functionality added in `1.13.0`)  -

```
In [160]: A2D = A.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,3)

In [161]: unq, st, ids = np.unique(A2D, axis=0, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)

In [162]: dict(zip(A[st], np.bincount(ids, b)))
Out[162]: 
{'a-1': 11.210000000000001,
 'b-1': 4.4400000000000004,
 'c-2': 11.199999999999999}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach, using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series(A),pd.Series(b)]).transpose()
res = df.groupby(0).sum()
```

gives

```python
res
Out[62]: 
         1
0         
a-1  11.21
b-1   4.44
c-2  11.20
```

You can get the dict you'd like to have like this:

```python
res_dict = res[1].to_dict()
```

Which gives

```python
Out[64]: 
{'a-1': 11.210000000000001,
 'b-1': 4.4400000000000004,
 'c-2': 11.199999999999999}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (dsiclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to perform these types of operations in an efficient and elegant manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
k, v = npi.group_by(A).sum(b)
d = dict(zip(k, v))
```

I feel that pandas is quite clunky with its grouping syntax; and that it shouldnt be necessary to reorganize your data into a new datastructure to perform such an elementary operation.

Comment: Althoug I agree with the clunkiness of converting to pandas' formats, you might want to add to your answer that you're the developer of that package, or it might be flagged as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302)